# Using more than one class

Tags: python, class, loops, initialization, pygame

Im writing a pygame and so far i have 2 classes

one that is the Main class a

and another that is used to draw images for later in the game

im trying to call the drawing part from the Main class

i got it to work fine the problem is i need to run the Draw classes `__init__` just once instead of looping it

here is where i call it:

```
if self.state == 2:
    if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.last_tick > 40:
        Draw().update(screen)
```

it works but there are variables in the init of the`Draw` class that need to be defined once instead of over and over again in the game loop

so how can i call this class so that the `__init__` runs but doesn't loop?

here is a link to the `Draw` class:

[The Draw Class](https://gist.github.com/C-Dubb/5847598)

thanks for reading all that if you can help please do!

Comment: Have you considered moving the constructor call outside the loop?

Comment: Ignacio's comment makes sense to me. Also, in your update method, you should probably replace the if's with 2-3 if/elif/then blocks. After all, you're looking for just 1 color & 1 size

Comment: ive tried alot of stuff but i get confused i just dont know how to correctly do it and @user1245262 yes ill fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do something like this:

```
the_class = Draw()

while looping:
    the_class.update()
```